# Beginner Python spam.py

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python, just got the learning python book and got stuck with the spam.py in the command line. The book says to make a file named spam.py and then ask python to run this by typing
%python spam.py
I have added the python to my PATH as it was C:\Python27 so I can call Python in the Windows CMD, but this just will not run. The error I receive is

```
>>>python spam.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python spam.py
              ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I appreciate any help that you can give.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you're trying to run your code from *within the Python interpreter itself* (the `>>>` prompt is the giveaway here since that's the Python prompt).

Exit from the interpreter (with CTRL-Z and ENTER for Windows) and run it from `cmd.exe` (the `c:\>` is the prompt in the example below):

```
c:\> python spam.py
```

From *within* the interpreter, you can also run an external file with:

```
execfile('spam.py')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. When i run this from CMD after exiting python i still receive an error. I type  python spam.py and i receive the following error. python: can't open file 'spam.py': (Errno 2) No such file or directory. The only way I could get it to run is by typing in the entire file path ex. C:\Users\testad\Desktop\spam.py. I was just trying to following the book to use the python spam.py

Comment: @user3221720, that's a different issue. If your current working directory is not the one where your script is, you will need to specify the path or `cd \Users\testad\Desktop` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code from `spam.py`...

You seem to be trying to run the spam.py from the Python interpreter. Go to where the file is in Windows Explorer and launch it from there, using the C:\Python2.7\python.exe CLI.

By the way, since you didn't understand the syntax error warning, please see:

- http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/SYNTAX
- http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/SEMANTICS

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute Python script file within the interpreter. Come out from the Python interpreter by pressing CTRL+Z and then ENTER key.
Then execute with the command :

```
 Say,  C:/> python spam.py
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a python program you have to run program in **Command Line** ***not*** in **Python Interpreter** 
(press `Windows Sign + R` and type `cmd.exe`)
Moreover you have to remember to be exactly in the directory where your file is saved, e.g.:
If the file file is `C:\Python27\spam.py` you have to be in `C:\Python27`.
To change the directory:

- use `dir` to display the folders and files in current place
- use `cd` to change your directory (e.g. `C:\Python27\>cd Spam` moves you to `C:\Python27\Spam`
- use `Tab` key to autocomplete names of the commands, folders and files

As you said you have added Python to PATH and followed my instructions, the statement below should work perfectly

> python spam.py

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If for example, your file is in G: drive, type this in cmd:
`python G:/myfile.py`
Basically, type in the path. Just doing "cd" won't work in Python